# Total Price Django

Tags: django

How can i get "total" price of items of OrderItem in cart model from these models down below? I tried doing something in views but I get attribute error that QuerySet' object has no attribute 'total'.

views.py

```
def cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(order_user=request.user)
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(cart__in=cart)
    total = 0
    for i in order_items:
        total = i.quantity * i.item.price + cart.total
        cart.update(total=total)

models.py

    class OrderItem(models.Model):
        cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
        item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
        quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Item(Visits, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price =  models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', default='static/images/man.png')
    description = models.TextField(default="Item")
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)



class Cart(models.Model):
    order_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="100 = 1EUR")
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='carts', through=OrderItem )
```

Comment: Get the total of what?  Of a given `Cart`?  The total of all of the `Cart` objects?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django total price of OrderItems in Cart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69065927/django-total-price-of-orderitems-in-cart)

Answer (score 2):

Just aggregate the total of ModelField `total` of the queryset like so

```
Total = Cart.objects.all().aggregate('total')

# Filtered in your case
Total = Cart.objects.filter(order_user=request.user).aggregate('total')
```

Apply filtering as necessary.
Also I suggest to have a good read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/aggregation/)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the cart information for current users via the OrderItem model itself.

Check how [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) works

```
from django.db.models import Count
order_items = (OrderItem.objects.filter(cart__order_user=request.user)
               .annotate(total=Count("quantity")*(item__price) + cart__total)
    
            )
```

Comment: item__price  and cart__total is not defined error

Comment: Do you want cart total?