# Django total price of OrderItems in Cart

Tags: django

How can I get "total" price of items of `OrderItem` in cart model from these models down below? I tried doing something in views but I get attribute error that `QuerySet object has no attribute 'total'`

```
# views.py

def cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.filter(order_user=request.user)
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(cart__in=cart)
    total = 0
    for i in order_items:
        total = i.quantity * i.item.price + cart.total
        cart.update(total=total)

# models.py

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart', on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=CASCADE, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

class Item(Visits, models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    price =  models.IntegerField(default=1000)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='pictures', default='static/images/man.png')
    description = models.TextField(default="Item")
    visits = models.IntegerField(default=0)



class Cart(models.Model):
    order_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=CASCADE)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total = models.IntegerField(default=0, help_text="100 = 1EUR")
    order_items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, related_name='carts', through=OrderItem )
```

Comment: why do you open multiple threads https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69064355/total-price-django

Answer (score 2):

You can get the total through [**`.annotate(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) and thus calculate this at the database side:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

def cart(request):
    cart = Cart.objects.annotate(
        price=Sum(F('orderitem__item__price') * F('orderitem__quantity'))
    ).get(
        order_user=request.user
    )
    cart.total = cart.price
    cart.save()
    # …
```

The `cart` object that arises from this will have an extra attribute `.price` that contains the price of the items multiplied with the corresponding quantity.

But this also specifies why you should *not* keep a `total` field in your `Cart`: you can calculate that when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is coming from the first line inside the for loop where you've written:

```
total = i.quantity * i.item.price + cart.total
```

Here, the cart is a `QuerySet` since you've used `filter` when you retrieved the `cart` object from *Cart* model in the first line of **cart** method. `filter` returns `QuerySet`, not object. You can use `get` to get the `cart` object since there is a OneToOne relationship between the *Cart* and *User* models. Try this in the first line of your **cart** method:

```
cart = Cart.objects.get(order_user=request.user)
```

You also need to use `save` method instead of `update` when you want to update an object. `update` method belongs to QuerySet only.

Comment: Okay sir but then i got and error 'Cart is not iterable' and i can not return it as a context.

Comment: Since `cart` now contains the Cart object and not the QuerySet, you need to change the second line to `order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(cart=cart)`. This will solve the "Cart is not iterable" issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
class OrderItem(DateTimeModel):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_items")
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_length=100, default=0, max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, default=0)
# need to add tax percentage along with it tax may be changed in future so we need to add tax percentage in this

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.id} - {self.order}"

def get_total(self):
    return round(float(self.price) * float(self.quantity))

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.total = self.get_total()
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```